Why does the alert trigger before the conditions are met
Why does the alert trigger before the conditions are met? What is wrong with this if statement?
I am trying to use the variable longconf as confirmation for the trigger but every time I turn the alert on, it is triggered when it crosses below ma3 which isn't part of the condition trigger. It's like it is completely ignoring my condition.
ma1_above = ta.crossover(close, ma1[offset1])
ma2_above = ta.crossover(close, ma2[offset2])
ma3_above = ta.crossover(close, ma3[offset3])
ma1_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma1[offset1])
ma2_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma2[offset2])
ma3_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma3[offset3])`

// Variables for tracking trade conditions
varip longconf = false



This is a typical example of repainting. As a bar is live, with each new tick, your script will be executed and your conditions will be calculated. So, their values might change during the lifetime of the bar.
You can add barstate.isconfirmed to your conditions. That way, it will update your condition on the last tick of the current bar.

still didnt fix the issue is about the if conditions also i added offset so regardless it shouldnt repaint

It could still repaint even if you use offset. Is the issue that you are getting alerts and there are no labels etc. on your chart? Or you are getting alerts when they don't make any sense?

Are you also sure that you want to use a varip variable?

you are the only one who replied thank u soo much
the problem was that visualy for me the code looks ok but i forgot  to add multipler in the calculation of the variable that caculates the if conditions
ma1_above = ta.crossover(close, ma1[offset1]*multiplier1)
ma2_above = ta.crossover(close, ma2[offset2]*multiplier2)
ma3_above = ta.crossover(close, ma3[offset3]*multiplier3)
ma1_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma1[offset1]*multiplier1)
ma2_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma2[offset2]*multiplier2)
ma3_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma3[offset3]*multiplier3)

the problem was that visualy for me the code looks ok but i forgot  to add multipler in the calculation of the variable that caculates the if conditions
ma1_above = ta.crossover(close, ma1[offset1]*multiplier1)
ma2_above = ta.crossover(close, ma2[offset2]*multiplier2)
ma3_above = ta.crossover(close, ma3[offset3]*multiplier3)
ma1_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma1[offset1]*multiplier1)
ma2_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma2[offset2]*multiplier2)
ma3_below = ta.crossunder(close, ma3[offset3]*multiplier3)

